# How to send dynamic data in Retrofit API calls in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add dynamic data in my api calls so using retrofit I am trying this:

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: Constants.baseUrl)
abstract class AppServiceClient {
  factory AppServiceClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _AppServiceClient;

  @GET("/get-all-country")
  Future<AllCountryResponse> getCountries();

  @GET("/get-state/{input}")
  Future<AllCountryResponse> getStates(@Path("input") instance<StateId>().fetchCountryId);
}
```

This is my statId class:

```
class StateId {
  StateId();
  String countryId = "";

  String get fetchCountryId => countryId;

  setCountryId(String value) {
    countryId = value;
  }
}
```

I want to pass a dynamic data in the get-state api. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this, it was adding field to the parameter

```
@GET("/get-state/{id}")
  Future<AllCountryResponse> getStates(@Path("id") String id);
```